# jQuery-Autocomplete - how to style by category

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

[jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) provides styles for the highlighted element, the rest of the elements, and groups of elements, but what I'd like to do is style things according to category. I have a list of names that can be either male or female; I'd like to make the background pink for female and blue for male.

The data list looks like this (and is arbitrary and could change to whatever):

```
 { value: username, data: { category: gender } }
```

I could do this by simply adding a "male" or "female" class to the end of the CSS classes if I could figure out how to do it. There are a lot of questions here about style, but none about styling data by category. (Also, a lot of the answers are outdated-- some say to use `formatItem`, which is deprecated. Other answers are actually for jQuery UI, which is different. I'm using [jQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).)

I've tried using the `groupBy` option, but that isn't exactly what I'm looking for (and still wouldn't let me color code the groups anyway).

I'm looking into overriding the `suggest` method, which contains this line:

```
 html += '<div class="' + className + '" data-index="' + i + '">' + formatResult(suggestion, value) + '</div>';
```

But if there's a simpler (or better, a proper) way to do it I'd rather do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to manipulate the container using `beforeRender` and looping through through the suggestions and the container:

```
...
beforeRender: function (container) {        
    $( container.children() ).each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass( $('#autocomplete').autocomplete().suggestions[index].data.category );  
    })
    return container;
},
...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uveqkokn/2/